# Replace with some keyword

Tags: java

I have extracted some keywords from excel and I have stored them in an array list. I search words in the text file by using these extracted keywords. I want to replace these keywords and store them in database.

This is my approach:    **Text Replacement**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt")) 

        .filter(s -> s.contains(arra.get(6)))
        .forEach(list::add);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output - the whole line

`[Compte de facturation : 9355941544]`

Expected only: Right-hand side part only (the value after `:`)

`[9355941544]`

Comment: What is actually wrong?

Comment: What is `arra`?

Comment: I want output 9355941544   like this..... Incoming loops i have many keywords so please help me

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please start with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and feel free to edit the post. some points 1) its so complex what are you asking for- you are asking for the text replacement, or how to store data in excel / DB ? 2) what did you tried and what are the errors which you are facing? If nothing, then first try to come with some own effort, please. Thanks in advance

Comment: it holds data extracted from excel

Comment: for kiss: instead of forEach(list::add); -> forEach(element -> list::add(  element.split(":")[0] ); or smth similar .. you get the idea - right?

Comment: You want output as `9355941544`? well, then answer can be `System.println("9355941544 ");`...
What are these number coming from? Will they be everytime the same, or you are referring to some variable??? , etc..

Comment: what ??? can you tell elaborately @ kai

Comment: Are your lines always `Some word : A number`?

Comment: No some time text will also be thier @ lino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the value after `:` only, then split each line by this symbol and get right part:

```
List<String> list = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt"))
        .filter(s -> s.contains(arra.get(6)))
        .map(s -> s.split(":")[1].trim())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```